# Adding many scrolledpanels to one scrolledPanel in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Level: Beginner

I am developing a GUI with wxPython on Windows 7 OS. Python version is 2.7 ad wxPython version is 3. My GUI looks as shown in the image below:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to take some time to explain what I am trying to achieve. As you mayhave noticed from the first image that there are 4 different scrolled panels in my GUI named as `panel-1 to panel-4`. A vertical BoxSizer is applied to each scrolled panel. Each scrolled panel in return contains a boxsizer and a horizontal `wx.StaticLine`. The reason for using horizontal line was to make it is easier for the user to read the values for a particular serial number. (It will be easy for an user to read all the values in different panels for a particular serial number.) Finally all these four scrolled panels are added to a horizontal BoxSizer named as `panelSizer`. Currently the scrolled panels are scrolling individually. One important thing is that all the scrolled panels will every time contain same number of components/elements.

Problem:

I need a way so that I can add all these scrolled panels to one sizer or a panel in such a way that there is only one scroll bar at right side and when I scroll this scrollbar all the scrolled panels (panel-1 to panel-4) should scroll simultaneously. I would like to have something like this:[image: image 2]

I think this option is better from the GUI perspective. I have tried couple of things like, I created a new scrolled panel named as `main panel`, and applied the BoxSizer named as `panelSizer` (it contains all the panel from panel-1 to panel-4) using `SetSizer()` function, but the scroll bar doesn't appears, even the individual scroll bars doesn't appear! Also, I have checked that there are enough components in the panels so that scroll bars appears. I tried to change the four scrolled panels to simple panels and then add to the panelSizer and then applied the sizer to the `main panel` but nothing solved the problem..

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my approach? Any suggestion. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your method that add 4 panel into one scrolled panel should work. Try to resize the scrolled panel to smaller window to see if the scroll bar appear.

Comment: @Jerry_Y, It's not working unfortunately. I tried resizing. I have 12 components in panel-1 but only 9 are being showed. But no scroll bars are displayed.

Comment: It would be better if you can post your code.

Comment: @Jerry_Y I found the solution while creating a minimal example to post here. Thanks for asking me to post the code. The solution is to disable scrolling on the scrolled panels named as panel-1 to panel-4. This can be done by not using SetupScrolling() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution myself so here it goes.

I have to disable scrolling on the panels-1 to panel-4. This can be done by not using `SetupScrolling()` method on them. Also, the scrolling should be enabled on the mainPanel like this:

```
mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
```

For an example: Consider that you have two scrolled panels named as `panel1` and `panel2`. Now if you want to add these two scrolled panels to an other scrolled panel named as `mainPanel`, then you first create these two scrolled panels and then disable scrolling on them then add these two panels two a sizer, then apply this sizer to the `mainPanel`. 
Code example:

```
mainPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
panel1 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
panelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
panelSizer.Add(panel1)
panelSizer.Add(panel2)
mainPanel.SetSizer(panelSizer)
```